# Split String and Replace Original String with Constituents

Tags: python, string, replace

Let's say I read in an input file with the String "Taco>Bell" and I want to replace that String with "Taco>" and "Bell". In other words, I want to replace one String with two. I know how to use the split method with regular expressions to split the String, but how do I perform the replacement?

Each time there is a String that has a ">" followed by a non-space character, I want to insert a space between the characters.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do here.  Maybe if you add more information, or a before and after what the file would look like.

Comment: Sure. 
Before: John likes to eat Taco>Bell
After: John likes to eat Taco> Bell

Comment: Yes, that's all I would like to do. Sorry if this is a really basic question.

Comment: See if my answer is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I knew how to do the replacement if I know what the String will be ahead of time, but what about the general case in which I'm reading from an input file and I don't know what it will be?

Comment: What is the rule you're using to replace on?

Comment: Each time there is a String that has a ">" followed by a non-space character, I want to insert a space between the characters.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need a look ahead, like so:

```
import re

mystring = "John likes to eat Taco>Bell because it is Bar>Foo healthy third> ok."

print mystring

mystring = re.sub(r">(?! )", "> ", mystring)

print mystring
```

Basically, the substitution only happens if the character following the `>` is not a space.

Output:

```
John likes to eat Taco>Bell because it is Bar>Foo healthy third> ok.
John likes to eat Taco> Bell because it is Bar> Foo healthy third> ok.
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible non-regex solution would be

```
>>> somestr.replace(">","> ").replace(">  ","> ")
'John likes to eat Taco> Bell because it is Bar> Foo healthy third> ok.'
```